# Pariwise joint continuity with one argument in common implies full joint continuity?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f(y,x_1,x_2,x_3) : [0,1]^4 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that

1. for each fixed $(x_1,x_2) \in  [0,1]^2$, $(y,x_3) \to f(y,x_1,x_2,x_3)$ is continuous.
2. for each fixed $(x_2,x_3) \in  [0,1]^2$, $(y,x_1) \to f(y,x_1,x_2,x_3)$ is continuous.
3. for each fixed $(x_1,x_3) \in  [0,1]^2$, $(y,x_2) \to f(y,x_1,x_2,x_3)$ is continuous.

That is, $f$ is pairwise joint continuous with $y$ in common.

Then, I wonder if $f$ is in fact fully continuous with respect to $(y,x_1,x_2,x_3)$ on $[0,1]^4$.

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: A simpler related question might be, given a function $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ of two variables, such that $f(\cdot,y),f(x,\cdot)$ are each continuous for fixed $y,x$ respectively, whether $f$ itself is continuous. This is false, however, with the example
$$
f(x,y) := \begin{cases}
\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}, & (x,y) \ne (0,0) \\
0, & (x,y) = (0,0)
\end{cases}
$$
This function is continuous separately in each variable (one should show that $f(x,y) \to 0$ for any $x$ as $y \to 0$, and for any $y$ as $x \to 0$). [cont.]

Comment: However it is not continuous altogether, as taking $(x,y) \to (0,0)$ along $y=x$ gives a limit of $1/2$. Perhaps this fact is helpful to you.

Comment: @PrincessEev I am aware of that example. That is the reason for presence of the "common" argument $y$ in my question.